# How to synchronously shutdown WPF application?

Tags: wpf, multithreading, application-shutdown

[App.Current.Shutdown()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdown.aspx) works asynchronously. It means that when you invoke this method you are not protected from execution of lines of code which follow the invokation of Shutdown().

So the question is how to block a thread from which App.Current.Shutdown() is invoked?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        App.Current.Shutdown();

        File.WriteAllText(@"..\log.txt", "Info");    
    }
}

 private void App_OnExit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e) {
        Thread.Sleep(3500);
    }
```

File.WriteAll will create a new file and write into it "Info" string.

Comment: `Shutdown` method should always be called from Main Thread. And I guess `Shutdown` should freeze the main thread. Are you seeing different behavior? Could you show your code and tell us more what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`App.Current.Shutdown()` is not working asynchronously according to documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597013.aspx

`Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown()` is working async.

**UPD**

I've tested your code. You are right. And documentation about `App.Current.Shutdown()` is misleading. Code after `App.Current.Shutdown()` in current method will be executed. Therefore `App.Current.Shutdown` should be the last statement before return (and also respecting method call tree).

As alternative to call `Environment.Exit(0)` but it could be considered as trick and hack, because in the fact it terminates process either gracefully or not, when gracefully isn't possible.

Comment: I have edited my question. Try Write to a file and convince yourself that App.Shutdown works very strange.

Comment: @EngineerSpock Amyway its hard to find why it functioning so, even Reflector doesn't help. Similar to yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601875/application-current-shutdown-1-not-closing-wpf-app

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple WPF application and replicated your code. The shutdown is not working asynchronously in it. The application was closed immediately when i click the close button.

```
 <Grid>
    <Button x:Name="btnClose" Height="50" Width="100"  Click="btnClose_Click_1"  Margin="265,135,152,135">Close</Button>
</Grid>**strong text**

 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        }

        void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnClose_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Current.Shutdown();

            MessageBox.Show("test");
        }

        private void App_OnExit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3500);
        }
    }
}
```

else

You can then kill the process by using
      Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();

use System.Diagnostics namespace for it. This will work fine for you

Comment: Yes, I know. But it would be better to write to a file something. Because after app shutdown Windows can prevent opening new views.

Comment: Write File.WriteAllText(@"..\log.txt", "Info"); instead MessageBox.Show("test");

Comment: You can then kill the process by using
Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
use System.Diagnostics namespace for it. This will work fine for you

Comment: It looks like a dirty hack. Killing app may prevent Exit event handler code from execution.